# Python Sorting List of List

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have this list:

```
newlis = [[3, 6, 4, 10], [1, 9, 2, 5], [0, 7, 8]]
```

I want to sort it in a way that each list is sorted. For instance:

```
newlis = [[3, 4, 6, 10], [1, 2, 5, 9], [0, 7, 8]]
```

I tried to write this code:

```
for i in range(len(newlis)):
    if j in newlis[i] < newlis[i+1]:
        newlis[i],newlis[i+1]=newlis[i+1],newlis[i]
print newlis
```

It's not working though. Can someone please help me out? Built in function are not allowed.

Comment: Why aren't built in functions allowed?

Comment: Try reading about sorting algorithms.

Comment: I'd be very tempted to just implement [mergesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) myself and then do something like `newlis = [mergesort(i) for i in newlis]`

Comment: or bubble sort ... bubblesort is really easy

Answer (score 2):

There are many things wrong here (among which is that this sounds like a homework question and we aren't supposed to respond to those) but I will give you some helpful advice:
You are comparing element J in list I to list I + 1.

You would want to compare element J in list I to element J + 1 in list I.

Also, you appear to be attempting to sort backwards. You will end up with large left and small right.

Also this is not a sorting algorithm. What happens when you have an array like

```
[3,6,4,10] => [6,4,10,3]
```

which is still not ordered, at all. Sorting algorithms are simple, but not that simple. I recommend looking them up.

Comment: Also, check your syntax, you tried to shorthand that inner loop but j in list i doesn't return anything. Proper syntax would be `for j in range(len(i) - 1): if i[j] < i[j+1]`.... but that's not the major fix needed.

Answer (score 0):

In `if j in newlis[i] < newlis[i+1]:`, you are comparing sublists and not the elements of the sublists itself. You need two loops, one for iterating on `newlis`, and one for sorting the elements of each sublist of `newlis`.

A sample using [Bubble Sort](http://knowpapa.com/bs-py/):

[You can test it here:](https://repl.it/yCq)

```
>>> newlis = [[3, 6, 4, 10], [1, 9, 2, 5], [0, 7, 8]]

>>> for sublist in newlis:
...     for i in range(len(sublist) - 1):
...         if sublist[i] > sublist[i + 1]:
...             sublist[i], sublist[i + 1] = sublist[i + 1], sublist[i]

>>> print(newlis)
[[3, 4, 6, 10], [1, 2, 5, 9], [0, 7, 8]]
```

Links about Bubble Sort:

http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap10/subsection2.1.2.2.html
http://www.go4expert.com/articles/bubble-sort-algorithm-absolute-beginners-t27883/